# Website not expanding to show information hidden by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm learning Javascript/jQuery and trying to make it so that after the submit button is clicked, the website expands and shows the information related to the search (I have not made that part yet, however I'm using a test `div` to show where it would go, and it's not showing up in full. However, the website is not expanding and no scroll features are showing up.

This is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="end">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>League of Legends Summoner Stats</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="center">
    <select class="region_selector">
        <option value="NA">North America</option>
        <option value="EUW">EU West</option>
        <option value="EUNE">EU East</option>
        <option value="KR">Korea</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="title">
    <h1>LoL Stat Find</h1>
</div>
<div id="subtitle">
    <h3>Quickly Find Summoner Stats!</h3>
</div>
<button type="submit" id="search_button">Search</button>
<input name="summoner_name" type="text" maxlength="512" id="summoner_name" placeholder="Summoner Name" class="summoner" />
<script src="script.js"></script>
<div id="stats">
    <section id="main">
        <h1>THIS IS A TEST</h1>
        some more testing
        <br>this is another test
        <br>another
    </section>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the CSS:

```
body {
    background-image: url("background.jpg");
    width: 100%;
    background-size: 100%;
}
.region_selector {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 150px;
    /* bring your own prefixes */
    transform: translate(-100%, -50%);
    display: inline;
}
#summoner_name {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    /* bring your own prefixes */
    transform: translate(5%, -50%);
    display: inline;
}
.summoner {
    font-size: 14px;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
#search_button {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    /* bring your own prefixes */
    transform: translate(-50%, 100%);
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #1947D1;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    line-height: 1.8;
    appearance: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-color: #1947D1;
}
#title {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    /* bring your own prefixes */
    transform: translate(-50%, -110%);
    display:inline;
    color: white;
    font-size: 48px;
    -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: black;
}
#subtitle {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    font-size: 20px;
    /* bring your own prefixes */
    transform: translate(-50%, -130%);
    font-family: tahoma;
    -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: black;
    display: inline;
    color: #009933;
    font-style: bold;
}
#stats {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    /* bring your own prefixes */
    transform: translate(-50%, 200%);
}
```

This is the Javascript:

```
$(function () {
    $("#stats").hide();
});
document.getElementById('search_button').onclick = function () {
    var search = document.getElementById('summoner_name').value;
    $(function () {
        $("#stats").show();
    });
}
```

I'm new to HTML/CSS/JS so my code is probably all sorts of messed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since using jQuery, use it for registering the click handlers.... also the problem is the styles applied to `#stats`

```js
$(function() {
  $("#stats").hide();

  $('#search_button').click(function() {
    $("#stats").show();
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-image: url("background.jpg");
  width: 100%;
  background-size: 100%;
}
.region_selector {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 150px;
  /* bring your own prefixes */
  transform: translate(-100%, -50%);
  display: inline;
}
#summoner_name {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  /* bring your own prefixes */
  transform: translate(5%, -50%);
  display: inline;
}
.summoner {
  font-size: 14px;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
#search_button {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  /* bring your own prefixes */
  transform: translate(-50%, 100%);
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #1947D1;
  font-family: Tahoma;
  line-height: 1.8;
  appearance: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-color: #1947D1;
}
#title {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  /* bring your own prefixes */
  transform: translate(-50%, -110%);
  display: inline;
  color: white;
  font-size: 48px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: black;
}
#subtitle {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  font-size: 20px;
  /* bring your own prefixes */
  transform: translate(-50%, -130%);
  font-family: tahoma;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: black;
  display: inline;
  color: #009933;
  font-style: bold;
}
#stats {
  position: fixed;
  top: 1px;
  <!--here is the problem --> left: 50%;
  /* bring your own prefixes */
  transform: translate(-50%, 200%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="center">
  <select class="region_selector">
    <option value="NA">North America</option>
    <option value="EUW">EU West</option>
    <option value="EUNE">EU East</option>
    <option value="KR">Korea</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="title">
  <h1>LoL Stat Find</h1>
</div>
<div id="subtitle">
  <h3>Quickly Find Summoner Stats!</h3>
</div>
<button type="submit" id="search_button">Search</button>
<input name="summoner_name" type="text" maxlength="512" id="summoner_name" placeholder="Summoner Name" class="summoner" />
<div id="stats">
  <section id="main">
    <h1>THIS IS A TEST</h1>
    some more testing
    <br/>this is another test
    <br/>another
  </section>
</div>
```